# React native async function returns empty object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, frontend

I am trying to get a token stored in securestore, and pass it to url. When I try to call the api the value of the token is just an empty object. I am able to see the value t here if I alert in readToken function. Its not passed to getMovies function.

```
  const readToken = async () => {
    try {
      const storedToken = await SecureStore.getItemAsync('token');
      return storedToken;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  const getMovies = async () => {
    try {
       let url = 'https://someurl.de/api/getschichten/?userid=9&token='+readToken();
       alert(url);
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const json = await response.json();
      setData(json);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }
```

Comment: You need to `await readToken()` (it's async)

Answer (score 0):

So, I changed my code according to kipnodels. Here's my code that works

```
  let myToken = await readToken();
  let url = 'https://esm.nvii-dev.de/api/getschichten/?userid=9&token='+myToken;
```